# how do i get the sum of numbers in a field in an array? I am trying to get the sum of numbers in field[2]

Tags: php, html

here is what i have been working with

$site=$_POST['site'];

```
$dives = file("dives.txt");

foreach($dives as $record){
    $fields = explode(",", $record);
   if($site == $fields[0]){
       print"$fields[1] $fields[2] $fields[3]<br/>";
       $count++;
   }
}
print"Total Dives: $count <br/>"; 
print "Total time underwater for $site:";
```

Comment: What's inside `dives.txt` or what does `$fields[2]` return?

Comment: Natural Reef 28 
Cave 49 
Cave 49 
Artificial Reef 49  $field[2] contains the numbers. dives.txt contains 4 fields, the name of the site, the type of dive, the depth of the dive, and the duration of the dive.  The fields are separated by commas. I want the sum of the numbers in $fields[2]

Comment: $fields[2] returns those numbers and i want the sum of those numbers for the Total time underwater

Comment: You say you want the SUM but I dont see any SUM operation in your code.      Please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & always try to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a new `$sum` array and populate that array with `$fields[2]` and then use `array_sum()` to grab the total.

```php
$sum = [];

foreach ($dives as $record) {
    $fields = explode(",", $record);
    $sum[] = $fields[2];

    if ($site == $fields[0]) {
        print "$fields[1] $fields[2] $fields[3]<br/>";
        $count++;
    }
}

array_sum($sum);
```

Comment: array_sum(Array) this is what it prints out instead of the sum.

Comment: Roatan,Natural Reef,28,41
Roatan,Cave,49,67
Roatan,Cave,49,75
Roatan,Artificial Reef,49,28 this is what "dives.txt " looks like

Comment: @saineyJammeh That happens if your trying to print the function, you could use `printf(‘some words %d’, array_sum($sum))` where the `%d` is a placeholder for the sum digits, or instead of using the array method set `$sum` to 0, and use `$sum += $fields[2]` then you can use `$sum` in print like any other variable.